# Drawing and erasing line in android

Tags: android

How to draw a line (not a straight one just random continuous point(like we draw with pencil)) and then to erase it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is finger painting application

```
////////////******************* Pinting view *******************///////////////////
public class MyView extends View {
    int bh = originalBitmap.getHeight();
    int bw = originalBitmap.getWidth(); 

    public MyView (Context c)  {  
        super(c);
        //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw,bh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,bw,bh,true);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)) ;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);           
            /*mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw, bh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);*/
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {   
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
    ////////************touching evants for painting**************///////
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {             
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();     
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //if(mode == DRAW) { mView.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this); }
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }  //end of touch events for image
}// end MyView
```

for erase

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Comment: Thanks .. 
i will definitely try...!! this

Comment: Hey Raja, I am trying to erase the line on click of button using your Erase code. And it will works but After erasing once it will not able to draw again. What should I miss ?? :)

Answer (score 3):

What i did is i created a dynamic array with center points of the pencil line. If you want to make the pencil so sharp you need to record all the points in the array. And drew all the points with 1pixel radius circles. The radius can be changed as the sharpness of the pencil.

When you need to erase this, when you are in erase mode when your finger or pointer go through an already entered point in array you just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

public class MyView extends View {

```
    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on that answer.
for erase

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

you can draw again by

```
mPaint.setXfermode(null);
```